# CGAL (Specifically QT5) Installation Error

Tags: windows, qt5, cgal, vcpkg

I am trying to install 32-bit QT5 using CGAL on my computer (I already installed 32-bit CGAL). I have a Windows 11 laptop and I am using the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022. The commands I have put in have been:

```
        cd YOUR_DIRECTORY_FOR_CLASS
        git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
        cd vcpkg
        .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
        .\vcpkg.exe install yasm-tool:x86-windows
        .\vcpkg.exe install cgal
        .\vcpkg.exe install [cgal]qt5 --recurse
```

When I put in the QT5 command, .\vcpkg.exe install [cgal]qt5 --recurse, I get the error

```
    <unknown>:1:1: error: expected a port name here (must be lowercase, digits, '-')
        on expression: [cgal]qt5 --recurse
                   ^
        example:
        vcpkg install zlib zlib:x64-windows curl boost
```

I also tried this command: .\vcpkg.exe install qt5:x64-windows, but I got a build error, and according to the log files, the primary errors are

```
    WARNING: Failure to find: C:/.../vcpkg/buildtrees/qt5-base/x64-windows 
        dbg/src/widgets/qt5widgetsd_metatypes.json

    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
```

My Question is how do I install the 32 bit QT5? Am I using the wrong command with the first command I described? I am happy to provide more information concerning the issue if needed.

Comment: "[cgal]qt5" where did you read such a suggestion? "qt5:x64-windows" does not sound like 32 bits.

Comment: So, It was suggested in the instructions I used for the installation (given by the professor of the class that requires it). the x64 was done when I tried an alternative approach of installing 64 bit version, which also resulted in a build error